# Pattern repository with EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have class who inheritance `DbContext`, how do I work with it?

```
class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<MyModel> Models {get;set;}
}
```

Like this:

```
class Repository<MyModel>
{
   private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
   public async Task Add<MyModel>(MyModel item)
   {
       if(item == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException();

       var contains = await GetItemByName(item.UniqueNameAndThisNotId );     
       if(contains != null)
         throw new InvalidOperationException();
      _context.AddAsync(item);
      _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   public async Task<MyModel> GetItemByName(string uniqueNameAndThisNotId)
   {
      return await Task.FromResult(_context.Single(x => x.UniqueNameAndThisNotId == uniqueNameAndThisNotId));
   }
}
```

Or like this:

```
class Repository<MyModel>
{
   public async Task Add<MyModel>(MyModel item)
   {
       ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
       if(item == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException();

       var contains = await GetItemByName(item.UniqueNameAndThisNotId );     
       if(contains != null)
         throw new InvalidOperationException();
      context.AddAsync(item);
      context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
   public async Task<MyModel> GetItemByName(string uniqueNameAndThisNotId)
   {
      ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
      return await Task.FromResult(context.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UniqueNameAndThisNotId == uniqueNameAndThisNotId));
   }
}
```

Comment: `ApplicationDbContext` *is* already your repository. What do you gain from abstracting it?

Comment: @haim770 I use `Repository<T>` in different classes. My question is a simple example, in my project I have `IDataStore<T>` and implements CRUD methods in `ModelNameRepository<T>`, but the meaning remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to pass the context through the construct

```
    protected readonly ApplicationContext _context;
    public GenericRepository(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: You can check this here https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/repository-pattern-in-aspnet-core/